# How to use SBT javascript snippet in production

Tags: javascript, ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

Have I understood it correctly the easiest way to use SBT is to install the toolkit into a Domino server  using the OSGI plugin or use the bundled Tomcat server?

What is the correct way to use the snippets for production it is still expected to reference the playground database?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you install the toolkit's osgi plugin into the domino server's eclipse workspace folder in the data/domino directory

You can then open Domino Designer and extend the faces-config.xml. 
You should look at the OpenNTF.org Trouble Tickets http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=Trouble%20Tickets%20Notes-to-XPages%20Example